# Containers not starting when server starts despite restart policy

Tags: docker

Currently have nine containers running under Ubuntu Server Mantic Minotaur 23.10. All are configured with a restart policy of unless stopped.

If the server loses power and restarts, seven of the nine restart fine but two do not: Home Assistant and Portainer.

There is nothing I can see in the Docker logs that suggests it has even tried to start these containers and they just show up as exited when the server shut down or powered off.

If I start them manually they work fine.

Not using compose, and I can't see anything  different with these two containers.

Why are these two containers not starting when the others are?